# Após agrupar elementos, obter a quantidade de elementos por grupo

Tags: java, expressões-lambda, stream

Tenho esta classe:

```
public class Pessoa {

    private String nome;
    private int idade;
    private String estado;
    private char sexo;
    private String regiao;
   
    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

E estes dados:

| Nome | Idade | Sexo | Estado | Região |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rodrigo | 48 | M | Rondônia | Norte |
| Nathan | 11 | M | Rio Grande do Norte | Nordeste |
| Olívia | 26 | F | Bahia | Nordeste |
| Giovanna | 39 | F | São Paulo | Sudeste |
| Ana Laura | 15 | F | Tocantins | Norte |
| João Miguel | 25 | M | Paraná | Sul |
| Lucas Matheus | 23 | M | Goiás | Centro-Oeste |

Eu estou estudando *lambdas* e *streams*, e cheguei numa situação que não consigo reproduzir, mas que tenho quase certeza que as *streams* podem fazer.

Eu consigo fazer:

```
System.out.println(vindoDoArquivo.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pessoa::getRegiao)));
```

que vai me retornar as pessoas separadas pela região.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu estava pensando em fazer uma contagem dessas pessoas **através das streams** (pois é o objetivo, aprender a usar streams), que me retornasse a **quantidade** de pessoas separadas por região. Por exemplo:

```
{ SUL = 1 , NORDESTE= 2, SUDESTE= 1, NORTE= 2, CENTRO_OESTE= 1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta usar [`Collectors.counting()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting()):

```java
System.out.println(vindoDoArquivo.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pessoa::getRegiao, Collectors.counting())));
//                                               aqui ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

O segundo parâmetro de [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) é a chamada *reduction operation*. Basicamente, ela é aplicada para os elementos de cada grupo, reduzido-os a um único valor. No caso do `counting()`, ele retorna a quantidade de elementos.

O resultado será cada região tendo a sua respectiva quantidade de elementos:

```
{CENTRO-OESTE=1, SUDESTE=1, NORTE=2, NORDESTE=2, SUL=1}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado meu mano, eu tava a um tempão quebrando a cabeça nessa !!